# mod_rewrite httpd.conf: Block access to directories on HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am (learning) implementing a Front Controller pattern, redirecting all requests to index.php and appending as a query string (to be parsed later by PHP) via a mod_rewrite rule in httpd.conf, below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

**Problem 1:** This is also redirecting needed existing files, such as `domain.com/css/main.css`. Shouldn't `!-d` and `!-f` be preventing this?

**Problem 2:** I want to block access (403) to certain directories and their contents -- `domain.com/css/*`, `domain.com/js/*`, etc -- unless the request comes from `domain.com`.

**Exposition**

I have the following rule to block requests based on `HTTP_REFERER` (from a blog, can't find the link...), which by itself blocks all user requests:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
```

I want to add another condition, checking if REQUEST_URI is for anything in those directories, but am having trouble getting it to work. If I add the below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /?.*(css|js)/?.* [NC]
```

Then **everything** is redirected; without it, **everything** is blocked. So, the full mod_rewrite set is as below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /?.*(css|js)/?.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated; I've been searching for an answer all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Problem 1:** This is also redirecting needed existing files, such as `domain.com/css/main.css`. Shouldn't `!-d` and `!-f` be preventing this?

It's supposed to, but it's possible that mod_rewrite doesn't have the right context. Rewrite rules in server config behave a little differently than in, say, an htaccess file. Try placing the rules in a `<Directory>` container:

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/docuemntroot">

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [NC,L]

</Directory>
```

For Problem 2, you can simply add the regex to the rule itself:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*
RewriteRule \.(css|js)$ - [F,L,NC]
```

And make sure you use the `L` flag to prevent the second rule from getting applied.

Comment: Jon, thanks for your response. Your solution to Problem 2, placed in a `<Directory "/server/http">` container (my document root), worked well. Placing the Problem 1 rules in the same container after the Problem 2 rules, however, is causing an infinite redirect loop, which wasn't the case before. I thought perhaps `RewriteBase /`, but same behavior with or without. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I stand corrected; this has become a different problem: the redirect works fine with URLs in format `domain.com/blah`, but not `www.domain.com/blah`. Your original answer did the trick for the question asked, accepted.